# regex - delete text after first sentence

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, global

I was wondering how I would acomplish the following. Replace all text that starts ater a first sentence (march " ." until the end of the line, which ends with ~~ (match "~~")?

For example.

**Before:**

record 1~The weather is beautiful. It is 88 degrees outside~~

**After:**

record 1~The weather is beautiful~

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what language you're using This should match ..*(~~)  this ". It is 88 degrees outside~~". Then in your replace function put in "$1" or "\1" which will add ~~ back to the end of the phrase.

Answer (score 0):

```
/(?=\.)(.*)(?=~)/g
```

Should get you what you need. Just replace it with ''

Answer (score 0):

Do a regex replace using

`\..+?~(~)`

as the search query and `\1` as the replacement value.  This will match against the ~~ terminator but will leave only a single ~ behind, as requested.